# saving all filenames in a folder in windows

Tags: windows-7

Is their a way to output all file names in a folder in windows to a text file? For example,
a.pdf
b.pdf
c.pdf

in some folder A,

output in text file as,
a.pdf
b.pdf
c.pdf

I know this is a insignificant task in linux but how to do this in windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a cmd prompt window.

Use dir and redirect the output to a file:

```
dir /b > files.txt
```